# Forcing Rstudio to use a specific version of R on linux

Tags: r, linux, bash, rstudio

My Rstudio (on linux) runs R version 3.3.0 and I don't have a clue what's directing it to do so. I'm using a VM, where my .bashrc file loads R 3.3.1 where I also set the RSTUDIO_WHICH_R env' variable to R 3.3.1 using:

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=`which R`
```

I've also set these two in the .bashrc file of root, but that neither prevents Rstudio from using 3.3.0.

Any idea how to force Rstudio to use the R version I want?

Comment: You can just set it through Tools -> Global Options

Comment: Where specifically?

Comment: @SeanReddy not in the Linux version.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is almost as it appears in [this documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R), <s>but I worry that the shell command expansion doesn't apply when being exported. To find out, what does `echo $RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` return?</s> (tested, works fine).

Perhaps try executing `which R` and using that full path as the exported variable.

**Update**: From that documentation,

> Not that in order for RStudio to see this environment variable when launched from the Ubuntu desktop Applications menu (as opposed to from a terminal) it must be defined in the ~/.profile file.

Comment: Yeah I tried following that documentation - that's where I got the RSTUDIO_WHICH_R idea. which R returns /usr/local/R-3.3.1/bin/R and then echo $RSTUDIO_WHICH_R returns that as well, as set in my .bashrc file. Apparently Rstudio doesn't load that.

Comment: Also, are you starting RStudio from the command line or menu?

Comment: Unfortunately the ~/.profile doesn't work. I'm starting rstudio from the command line using: sudo /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rstudio-server start

Comment: You didn't mention it was the server version... That documentation has a section specifically for that, which points to the user manual, which says it *should* take the value from `which R`, but otherwise has an all-lowercase option to set in `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf`. Failing that, I'd recommend trying the RStudio Support as it's a software issue not an R issue.

Comment: and restart after editing `~/.profile` (or update otherwise)

Comment: Is there a way to specify the R version depending on the RStudio project? Setting `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` in `~/.profile` works. But this set the R version for all RStudio  sessions.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with RStudio Desktop.