# new version of R with rstudio

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, version

I installed a new version of R but rstudio still uses the old version. The command "which R" is just a shell script and I'm not sure how to get rstudio and the new version of R integrated. R base installed in /usr/share/doc.

Any tips?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: In Rstudio go to  `Tools > Global options > General > Change`, locate R version and select it.

Comment: @JilberUrbina I believe that works for Windows only ([source](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop)), which the text of the post implies is not what OP is using

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Yes, you hit on the bull's eyes, I'm running on Windows, sorry, I missed that part of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing Rstudio to use a specific version of R on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217149/forcing-rstudio-to-use-a-specific-version-of-r-on-linux). This is technically a duplicate of the previously mentioned question. However, as I think the answer could be a little more explicit, I've also added a more verbose answer below.

Answer (score 1):

See the [RStudio support pages](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop). In particular, for Linux, you have to set the `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` environment variable.

Comment: I tried export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R but it failed: "unexpected symbol" or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I'm running Linux Mint 17.

Answer (score 1):

As found out in the comments, you're on a Linux system, specifically Linux Mint 17. I can see three basic scenarios here:

1. You want to ensure RStudio uses a specific version of R when you are launching RStudio from the terminal as a one-time event.
2. You want to ensure RStudio uses a specific version of R every time you launch RStudio from the terminal.
3. You want RStudio to use a specific version of R when you launch RStudio from the applications menu (or, equivalently, via something like Synapse).

They are dealt with in turn below. I assume throughout that the path to the R binary you want RStudio to use is `/opt/R/3.1.0/bin/R`, which you should change as appropriate.

## One-time Terminal Launch

After opening a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, run

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/R/3.1.0/bin/R
```

Then, anytime you launch RStudio from the terminal via the `rstudio` command **in that terminal session**, it will use the specified R version. However, after you `exit`, the next time you open the terminal, it will no longer respect that choice.

## Every Terminal Launch

Use your favorite text editor to edit the file `~/.bashrc`. At the end, on a new line, add

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/R/3.1.0/bin/R
```

Then, either launch the terminal, or if you already have it open run the command `source .bashrc`. Then, you can launch RStudio via the command `rstudio` and it will use the version of R you want.

## Launching from the Applications Menu

Use your favorite text editor to edit the file `~/.profile`. At the end, on a new line, add

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/R/3.1.0/bin/R
```

Then you need to log out of your system and log back in. After that, anytime you launch RStudio from the application menu, it will use the specified R version.

Comment: I got it to work this way: Which R to locate R. Then delete R and Rscript.Then install new version of R and Rstudio. It worked.